# How to lock phone without pressing power button?

Tags: android-10

Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question, but how can I turn off the display without hitting the physical power button on Android 10 (Pixel 4a)? On my old phone I could customize long-press home or double-tap within launcher to do this. I enabled 3-button style but can't seem to find the settings for customization or for the Pixel launcher behaviour. I also couldn't figure out how to do this with gesture / swipe control.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with apps doing this for you, then you could try this app. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lsc.lock You tap on it and it'll lock your phone and turn off your screen as well.